# ¿Cómo detectar con BroadcastReceiver la vibración en android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Cómo debería hacer el

```
  filter.addAction();
```

para detectar la vibración del móbil? Y ¿Que permiso necesitaría?

Answer (score 1):

No, no hay manera de detectar ese servicio, puedes generar vibración pero no identificar cuando lo haga. No existe metodo isVibrated() o algo parecido. Puedes detectar si el dispositivo si puede o no vibrar,

> hasVibrator
>
> Added in API level 11 boolean hasVibrator () Check whether the
>   hardware has a vibrator.
>
> Returns boolean   True if the hardware has a vibrator, else false.

```
Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
boolean hasVibrator = mVibrator.hasVibrator();
```

Documentación de Vibrator

[Vibrator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //code...
      }
  };
  IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(
                  AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION);
  registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

En tu manifest agrega estos permisos.

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.RingerModeStateChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Veo que has puesto AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED_ACTION no me va a servir, necesito detectar la vibración de un juego através del service

Comment: Detectar la vibración con código es algo prácticamente imposible, lo que podes hacer es modificar una variable cada vez se ejecute la vibración, así podrás verificar via código.

Comment: El problema es que la vibración viene des de otra aplicación que no es mía. Me parece raro que no haya un receiver...

Comment: Encontré una librería que te puede ayudar https://github.com/tbouron/ShakeDetector

Comment: Gracias voy a probarlo!

Comment: El ShakeDetector no sirve para detectar la vibración.